# Closing ad popup window on webview not working onBackPressed

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm trying to close the ad popup window on webview onBackPressed. But it keeps reloading the ad window. I am using exoclick and juicyads popunders on the website.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView view = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    view.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    view.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    view.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    //view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
     });

    view.loadUrl("https://example.com");
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    WebView view = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    if (view.canGoBack()) {
        view.goBack();
        return;
    } else {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: where is your ad popup window code?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.juicyads.com/jp.php?c=3474w2z2u264u4q2q29453e464&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.juicyads.rocks"></script> Here it is.

Comment: The back press is being captured by the WebView, not by the Activity.